# Cómo contar elementos agrupados en SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo dos tablas:

- Jugadores
- Equipos

El campo 'nombre_equipo' de la tabla de jugadores coincide con el campo 'nombre' en la tabla de equipos.

Quiero saber **cuantos jugadores tiene cada uno de los equipos**. Mi consulta devuelve la lista con los nombres de los equipos, pero no el numero de jugadores por equipos.

```
`select nombre, (
  select count(s.nombre) 
   from jugadores s 
   join equipos e on e.nombre=s.nombre_equipo) as NUMERO_JUGADORES
    from equipos;`
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si la respuesta dada te fue util no olvides marcarla como aceptada y dar un voto positivo, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select e.nombreequipo, count(j.idjugador) as Jugadores
from jugadores j inner join equipos e on e.nombreequipo = j.nombreequipo
group by e.nombreequipo;
```

La cláusula group by se usa para hacer agrupaciones por uno o varios campos, y el count en el select es una función de agregación que para cada equipo va a devolver el total de los jugadores del mismo